# ipython/Jupyter notebook with authentication

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter on a [spark] cluster which has a public ip address. I want to make sure I am the only one that can see, change and basically has access to this notebook. How can I make this notebook whenever I open it to ask for some username/password by connecting it to PAM or something else?

Comment: You can configure it with a fixed password ([instructions here](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html#securing-a-notebook-server)). If you want to connect it to separate authentication like PAM, there's [Jupyterhub](http://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to do that.

Comment: Nice, thank you. This solves so many of my problems. Would you please add it as an answer, so that others can find it. I believe many people must care about this to export/share their work.

Comment: When using plain HTTP, I'm not sure how Jupyter "secures" the password when it is shipped to the server for verification -- if you are using an insecure network, I advise using SSL...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure Jupyter with a fixed password and HTTPS so you can expose it to the public internet and not let everyone in. [Here are the docs for that](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html#securing-a-notebook-server).

If you want to connect it to separate authentication like PAM, there's a separate layer called [Jupyterhub](http://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which can manage logins and starting notebook servers for logged in users.